# WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes when passing xml using cURL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml

I'm using rails 2.3.5, ruby 1.9.3, rubygems 1.8.24 and mac os x lion

I'm passing this file, "invoice.xml.erb" using cURL:

```
<invoice>
....
<invoice_detail>
....
</invoice_detail>
</invoice>
```

i was expecting to have the fields of invoice be filled and also the fields of invoice_details, but when I pass the cURL command, only the invoice fields are being filled, and this error occurs: WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: inventoryDocId, invoice_detail

here are my models:

invoice.rb

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name "inventoryDocHeader"
set_primary_key "inventoryDocId"
has_many :invoice_detail, :foreign_key => "inventoryDocId"
attr_accessible :inventoryDocId, :originDocId, :siteCode, :transCode, :typeCode, :docCode,    :partyTerms,:locationCode, :otherCharges, :grossPrice, :netPrice, :amountPaid, :amountPending, :amountReturned, :RSiteCode, :RInventoryDocId, :RDocCode, :ROriginDocId, :batchCode, :partyCharges, :partyShipmentTermsText, :estimateVolume, :originCountryId, :consigneeName, :consigneeAddress1, :consigneeAddress2, :consigneeAddress3, :notifyPartyName, :notifyPartyAddress1, :notifyPartyAddress2, :notifyPartyAddress3

 end
```

invoice_detail.rb

```
class InvoiceDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
set_table_name "inventoryDocDetail"
belongs_to :invoice, :foreign_key => "inventoryDocId"
attr_accessible :inventoryDocId, :lineNumber, :parentLineNumber, :productCode,   :actualQuantity, :unitCode, :contentQuantity, :cost, :price, :commission, :factorRate, :referenceLineNumber
end
```

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `:invoice_detail_attributes` to attr_accessible commands for the first error. With the second one are you getting it from Invoice or InvoiceDetails model?

Comment: I'm getting it from the invoice_detail, since the invoice fields are all filled.

Comment: then I will try adding `invoice_attributes` to attr_accessible in InvoiceDetail model